# VirtualBox crashed after Ubuntu Mate update

Tags: kernel, virtualbox, ubuntu-mate

I delete it & re-installed many times with different versions but the problem persists:

```
vboxdrv.sh: failed: Look at /var/log/vbox-setup.log to find out what went wrong.

sudo cat /var/log/vbox-setup.log
Building the main VirtualBox module.
Error building the module:
make V=1 CONFIG_MODULE_SIG= -C /lib/modules/4.4.0-145-generic/build SUBDIRS=/tmp/vbox.0 SRCROOT=/tmp/vbox.0 -j4 modules
make[1]: warning: -jN forced in submake: disabling jobserver mode.
mkdir -p /tmp/vbox.0/.tmp_versions ; rm -f /tmp/vbox.0/.tmp_versions/*
make -f ./scripts/Makefile.build obj=/tmp/vbox.0
  gcc -Wp,-MD,/tmp/vbox.0/linux/.SUPDrv-linux.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem .........
```

Failed versions:

- virtualbox-5.2_5.2.26-128414_Ubuntu_xenial_amd64.deb
- virtualbox-6.0_6.0.4-128413~Ubuntu~xenial_amd64.deb

My linux:

```
uname -a
Linux cent 4.4.0-145-generic #171-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 26 12:43:40 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

lsb_release -a 
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

Another failed retry to build the kernel:

```
sudo /sbin/vboxconfig
vboxdrv.sh: Stopping VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Starting VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
vboxdrv.sh: failed: Look at /var/log/vbox-setup.log to find out what went wrong.

There were problems setting up VirtualBox.  To re-start the set-up process, run
  /sbin/vboxconfig
as root.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: On another machine with Ubuntu 18 version virtualbox-6.0_6.0.4-128413~Ubuntu~xenial_amd64.deb does installs well though!!!

Comment: Install testbuilds from https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Testbuilds as described from @robco at the original answer. Don't forget to uninstall completely virtualbox as described by Luis Capriles: "sudo dpkg -l | grep virtualbox" and "sudo apt-get purge virtualbox..." in combination with any visual tool like Synaptic Package Manager for starters; still "dpkg" is useful as it found the virtualbox-qt library to be hanging around in my system. Good luck.